# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: proxy, nginx

I am using postal as my SMTP for my email marketing campaign.  I am currently using Putty open-source terminal emulator and winSCP basic file manager and file synchronization to put my project together.

I am unable to open my IP address I have set up for postal.  I have asked my current VPS provider to diagnose what the issue may be.  This is what I was told.

The issue is the following:

2020/10/13 21:53:15 [error] 24654#24654: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 178.238.239.246, server: postal.yourdomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "postal.cheerorganics.co"

This basically means that you have set Nginx as a reverse proxy to some service that listens on port 5000, however when seeing what services listen on what port (for instance with the netstat -punta command), there is no service that listens on that port.

PLEASE HELP!!!  FYI I am a newbie to this world.